# Candy Crush Saga Game Strategy

Tags: candy-crush-saga

**My Observation and understanding of the game**

I have been playing this game since a week-ten days. I some how feel the candies are not randomly generated, I also understand there are multiple variations of each level so that if played multiple times we get different starting of that level  (that's what i have noticed).

**My struggle**

I am struggling at "clear the jellies" and "bring down the ingredients" levels after 25. They getting tougher and tougher taking too many lives to complete them

**My Question**

Since this is a puzzle game and I hope and believe its not just the luck what we should rely on but some strategy to complete it.

What kind of strategy should I adopt?

Right now I am focusing on making special candies and clear the rows or columns by making stripe candies every now and then I get lucky to make color candie and its mostly luck that I get a wrapper candie

Comment: Are you talking about the mobile game Candy Crush Saga?

Comment: yes, its candy crush saga by king

Comment: There are certainly boards where the layout of the candies is predetermined (particularly the tutorial type boards where they want to show off a particular feature the first time you play them), but after that it seems clear that most of the candy is completely random.

Comment: pick a level and play it 10 times you will notice they repeated at least repeated trice

Comment: This game tries to make you think there is a strategy, but truth is 80% plus is pure luck!

Comment: I don't believe that the candy layouts are ever repeated, I've played the game a lot.

Comment: There is only one clear strategy -- it's Candy Crash author's monetization strategy :-P

Comment: The candies are generated more or less randomly, on my android, I will start a level and if I don't like the look of it I will simply quit without making a move and restart. On my android this does not waste a life. But your current strategy is good, by strategy I mean luck. This game is mostly luck, and I noticed a pretty big difference between the fb version and mobile version. FB version is much easier

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a whole [guide](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/candy-crush-saga-tricks-tips-and-guide/) you can check out, but I'll summarize here:

- As others have mentioned, comboing your special candy can be quite powerful.  Each combination of two special candies, when matched, will produce a devastating effect on the board as a whole.  This is somewhat situational, though, since you're not always going to have the luxury of having a bunch of special candy that is easy to combo together.  However, getting your 4's, 5's, and 6's matched together is almost always a priority, since they create effects that can hit a wide swath of the board.
- Work from the bottom up.  The bottom candies tend to get stuck there and stay there, and more often than not you need fresh candy down there with lots of matches in order to clear the board.  Additionally, moving candies at the bottom tends to create "free" matches at the top that boost your score and keep the candies moving.
- The hint system is terrible, so avoid following its instructions.  It will often tell you to match 3 and break up a match of 4/5.
- You can repeatedly enter and exit levels to re-roll the starting candies.  (At least on the Android version, this does not cost you a life, **unless** you make a move first or the level has a timer)  This is especially important where you need to clear the bottom quickly - you can reroll until you've got a 5 match or a couple of 4's, or even several 3's along the bottom.

That said, the game *is* very random.  The whole point appears to be to make the game just hard enough that you get near the end but frequently fail.  The way the company makes money is when you lose and either buy new lives or attract new players who will hopefully spend money.  Therefore, they've got a vested interest in putting you in unwinnable (but not discouragingly so) situations.

I've rolled several of the levels 20-30 times in service of finding easier starting positions, and I can assure you that the starting candies are quite random.  The objectives tend to be in the same positions, or at least have a fixed spawning pattern in the case of "ingredient" levels, however.

Comment: One thing that's not correct about your guide is about "matching two of the same type of special candies together." Matching two bombs together blasts a _huge_ area, _twice_ (I *think* it's 6×6) and really can be a level solver. Matching two striped candies will always cause one to stripe horizontally and one to stripe vertically, regardless of what direction the stripes actually are. If the two candies are same-striped, the candy you move keeps its orientation and the other's changes; this is important to keep in mind when it does make a difference.

Comment: (The other thing that's not correct is mystery quests. They're actually levels chosen at random from the ones you've left behind; the points requirement however is at 2 or even 3 stars. If you fail a level and hit "Retry", the screen should give you the level number. Especially as you progress Mystery Quests become much, _much_ easier than the levels in the episode you've just finished)

Comment: @badp, I don't believe they used to pick randomly from levels you'd finished - the first set I had (before the patch where they changed the whole UI for the feature) were different levels altogether.  I'm still learning more about the candy combos as I play, so that needs an update.

Answer (score 3):

A tactic that got me a few levels further, is to save the special candies so an other special candy ends up next to it. Combining special candies always gives a larger effect. Cross-using different species of special candies gives a huge effect.

Try to prepare candies for a huge combo. Make sure the candy drops in place so you can create, for example, a wrapper candy. Keep in mind that it can take 3 turns to create such candy.

Comment: 2 chocolate donuts (i think thats what they are) when combined, clear the entire board! Which is extremely useful for the Jelly levels :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the Candy Crush Saga by King, then creating 'Jazzles' is your best bet. If you manage to create one of these, I'd advise using it with a 'Special Candy' so that all the candy of that colour, change into special candies - thus clearing more of the board.

Answer (score 2):

Try to combine a striped candy with a little bag of candy then it will remove all the candy's 
in a vertical and a horizontal row of 3 by 3 wide

Answer (score 2):

I really think the key to successfully completing any level of CC is having a good initial layout to begin with. Therefore knowing how to exit & re-enter a level to enable a reshuffle is crucial.

The trick is to hold off hitting the PLAY Button until you see a layout that looks favourable for the level you are playing. (ie: you can see an instant 5 candy combo or vertical/horizontal 4 candy combos) That way, you're at least off to a very good start.

My husband plays CC on his iPad and he's used the exit/re-enter strategy often, and with great success. This does not work on the Facebook or Android versions, however.